# Destiny taken king legendary edition- digital download

Tags: destiny

I have a PS3, and am thinking about getting the legendary edition. However, I am changing to ps4 soon, so I was wondering if I got it for my PS3, when I got ps4, would it be there to download?

Comment: Thnelegendary edition is digital, off the playstation store

Comment: I think the answer is no, but I cannot confirm: https://www.destinythegame.com/digital-upgrade  It seems you only could do so with the Y1 content/expansions.  This page was updated for the TTK, but does not mention a free download on the next gen.

Comment: If you are getting a PS4 soon, you are better of waiting to purchase TTK until you get your PS4

Comment: The Legendary Edition is on the Sony store for PS4, and it includes the base game and the Y1 expansions; The Dark Below & House of Wolves: https://store.playstation.com/#!/en-gb/games/destiny-the-taken-king-legendary-edition/cid=EP0002-CUSA00568_00-DESTINYTAKENLEGE You would have to buy the game again to play on PS4.

Answer (score 1):

No, each system has a separate game and both would need separate downloads. (Two separate purchases.)  If you bought it on PS3, the option to download would show up on PS3 and the option to buy would show up on PS4.